# Installing LyX 2.3.5.2 on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, aptitude, texlive, lyx

I am trying to install `LyX 2.3.5.2` on `Ubuntu 20.04 LTS` with the following code:

```
sudo aptitude install lyx
```

It throws the following message. Any hints to solve the problem.

```
sudo aptitude install lyx
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  dvisvgm{a} enchant{a} fonts-lmodern{a} libenchant1c2a{a} libptexenc1{a} libteckit0{a} libtexlua53{a} libtexluajit2{a} libzzip-0-13{a} 
  lmodern{a} texlive-base{a} texlive-binaries{a} texlive-latex-base{a} texlive-plain-generic{a} 
The following packages will be upgraded:
  lyx{b} lyx-common 
The following packages are RECOMMENDED but will NOT be installed:
  dvipng texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-latex-extra texlive-latex-recommended texlive-science 
2 packages upgraded, 14 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 78.6 MB/89.3 MB of archives. After unpacking 232 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 lyx : Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but it is not installable
       Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.8.0) which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package

       Depends: libqt4-svg which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package

The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     lyx [2.3.4.2-2 (focal, now)]                       
2)     lyx-common [2.3.4.2-2 (focal, now)]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository) or use package from [*groovy*](https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/lyx).

Comment: Please also add output of `apt-cache policy lyx` to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install QT4 as it is dependency of lyx. QT4 is not available in official Ubuntu 20.04 repository.
You can install it via Rock Core Team PPA.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rock-core/qt4
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install qtwebkit
```

Comment: This should not happen at all, the LyX for [groovy](https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/lyx) depends on Qt5 as it should be.